# pyenvでpython3のインストールに失敗する

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

macOS High Sierra 10.13.2です。

```
pyenv install 3.6.4
```

とすると、下記のようなエラーになります。

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.13.2 using python-build 20160602)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/66/rr7sz_v92mbcdzrw1yj8md0h0000gq/T/python-build.20180116170918.43667
Results logged to /var/folders/66/rr7sz_v92mbcdzrw1yj8md0h0000gq/T/python-build.20180116170918.43667.log

Last 10 log lines:
    import pip
  File "/var/folders/66/rr7sz_v92mbcdzrw1yj8md0h0000gq/T/tmp7a7v0c9u/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/66/rr7sz_v92mbcdzrw1yj8md0h0000gq/T/tmp7a7v0c9u/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "/var/folders/66/rr7sz_v92mbcdzrw1yj8md0h0000gq/T/tmp7a7v0c9u/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/66/rr7sz_v92mbcdzrw1yj8md0h0000gq/T/python-build.20180116170918.43667/Python-3.6.4/Lib/plistlib.py", line 65, in <module>
    from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
  File "/private/var/folders/66/rr7sz_v92mbcdzrw1yj8md0h0000gq/T/python-build.20180116170918.43667/Python-3.6.4/Lib/xml/parsers/expat.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pyexpat import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyexpat'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

下記のようにしても同様のエラーになります。

```
CFLAGS="-I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" pyenv install 3.6.4
```

これでもエラーになります。

```
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" pyenv install -v 3.6.4
```

3.6.1~3.6.4まで試しましたが同様にエラーになります。
Xcodeコマンドラインツールはインストールされています。

解決方法をご存知の方がいましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/993 を定期的に見ているといいかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

私も同様のエラーに悩まされましたが、以下リンクのjklemmさんのコメントにある方法で解決しました。
OS10.13.6で実施し、問題なくインストール出来ました。

> ```
> unset CFLAGS
> brew install pyenv readline xz
> pyenv install {{version}}
> ```
>
> https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1066#issuecomment-387211005

移行アシスタントをつかって移行後にこの現象が発生する事があるようです。